# Force ColorFunction to take same parameters as the function it colours

Tags: plotting

`ColorFunction` doesn't behave as I expect. It doesn't seem to take the same value as the function itself. See below. I plot the function `Sin[x]^2` and use it to specify the opacity of the curve. Hence I would expect the tops of the curves to be visible, and to fade away to invisible at the bottom. Instead I get the following behaviour. Any explanation?

```
Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Opacity[Sin[x]^2, Blue]]]
Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 8 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Opacity[Sin[x]^2, Blue]]]
```

[image]

I think the problem is something to do with rescaling. If I plot in the range `{x, 0, 1}` then it works as expected.

```
Plot[Sin[20 x]^2, {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Opacity[Sin[20 x]^2, Blue]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Read under Details in the ColorFunction documentation—first argument is x, second is y when using Plot.  Use the second.

Comment: I read it. I don't understand. I want `x` to be the argument. But it seems to be rescaling the range of `x` to be in `{0,1}`

Comment: `f=Sin[x]; Function[x, Opacity[f, Blue]]` does not work because `x` does not appear literally in the function.  It must be inlined in some way: `Function[x, Opacity[Sin[x], Blue]]`. It's better to define `f` as a proper function that is called as `f[x]`.

Comment: No it still doesn't work. I'll update and you'll see.

Comment: Updated, so `x` appears literally. Problem is still there

Comment: Yes, you're right, the argument to the colour function is scaled to go from 0 to 1 unless you specify `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to use the second argument of the colour function. The meaning of each argument for each function is documented under Details in [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html).

```
Clear[f]
f = Sin[x]^2;
Plot[f, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Opacity[y, Blue]]]
```

To fix your example,

- Make sure `x` appears literally in the function
- Turn off [`ColorFunctionScaling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html)

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := Sin[x]^2
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Opacity[f[x], Blue]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```