How to use a function as an opacity control for another plot in Mathematica?
I have a function called eval3a[x_], where
eval3a[x_] = (-60 + 44 Cos[x] - 20 Cos[2 x] + 4 Cos[3 x] + 
     Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
       2154 - 2896 Cos[x] + 1915 Cos[2 x] - 888 Cos[3 x] + 
        278 Cos[4 x] - 56 Cos[5 x] + 5 Cos[6 x]])/(8 (15 Cos[x] - 
       6 (3 + Cos[2 x]) + Cos[3 x]));

When I plot this function using the following code:
prob3plot = 
  Plot[eval3a[x Degree], {x, 0, 180}, PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {0, 1}},
    Exclusions -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 20, ImageSize -> 400, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "prob"}];

It produces the following plot:

The function eval3a[x_] ranges between 0 and approximately 0.0894918. Now, I want to use eval3a[x_] as an opacity function for another function, say f[x_] = Cos[x]. Specifically, I want f[x_] to be invisible wherever eval3a[x_] = 0, and for its visibility to increase proportionally with the value of eval3a[x_].
In other words, I want the opacity of f[x] to be proportional to the value of eval3a[x_], so that f[x] only becomes visible where eval3a[x_] > 0, with full visibility when eval3a[x_] reaches its maximum value.
Is this possible to do in Mathematica?

Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192648/1871

@xzczd   Thank you!

You should probably include the code that produces the black background, since this question is about appearances.

@MichaelE2 There is no code. When I open a new *.nb file I go to Format->Stylesheet->ReverseColor Then when I generate a plot I right click on the cell, I then go to Background Color->Black

Nonetheless, if the code does not reproduce what is shown in the OP, then it feels like trouble to me. The OP is obviously doing something they are not telling us. What is it? It is going to cause problems? Plenty of site users post questions because they're doing something wrong — maybe it's because they're using $Post to put black backgrounds and it's messing with the color. Etc., etc. I would either explain what I'm doing (ok) or use a notebook with the default settings (better, imho), so that I and anyone trying to help would be generating the same output.

Here is a solution.
max = FindMaximum[eval3a[x Degree], {x, 90}][[1]];

normEval3a[x_] = eval3a[x Degree]/max;

f[x_] := Sin[x]^2
Plot[f[x Degree], {x, 0, 180}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Opacity[normEval3a[x], Blue]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]



